# Wordpress PHP If else to change div on different pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to write some php which will change the content of a div depending on which page is being shown. I'm a newbie to php so I'm sure I've written it all wrong...

```
<?php if ( is_page('home') ) { ?>
    <div class="strapline">stuff 1</div>
<?php elseif ( is_page('about') ) { ?>
    <div class="strapline">stuff 2</div>
<?php elseif ( is_page('services') ) { ?>
    <div class="strapline">stuff 3</div>
<?php elseif ( is_page('blog') ) { ?>
    <div class="strapline">stuff 4</div>
<?php elseif ( is_page('portfolio') ) { ?>
    <div class="strapline">stuff 5</div>
<?php elseif ( is_page('contact') ) { ?>
    <div class="strapline">stuff 6</div>
<?php elseif ( is_page('privacy-policy') ) { ?>
    <div class="strapline">stuff 7</div>
<?php else ( is_page('terms-and-conditions') ) { ?>
    <div class="strapline">stuff 8</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Could anyone help me figure this one out? Maybe it should be a loop? Thanks!

Comment: So what problem are you actually having? Is that not working?

Comment: No it's not... It's throwing a Server Error (500).

Comment: if you ever need to do so many if else calls I would recommend using a switch instead.  with an if else call even if the 1st if is valid it will still check all the other if elses in the list.  A switch will only run until it find the first valid statement and break which can mean it runs faster.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: @krisscross90 The 500 server error likely has nothing to do with this code. Typically even if you had a fatal PHP error, you would get a 200 HTTP response.  This is likely some other issue on your server.

Comment: If you comment out your entire block of code posted here do you still get a 500 error?

Comment: @Jrod If I take that code out it works fine! Think I'm gonna work on changing it to a switch and see if it works! Thanks for all your help!

Comment: There is nothing there that should be causing a 500 error.  Is this all your code? Are the `stuff 1`, `stuff 2` placeholders just text?

Comment: No I've got other code on the page. I don't seem to be getting the error now that I'm using a switch statement, however it's still not showing the information I want it to. I'll just keep working on it. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A switch would be better:

(assuming you have a function `get_actual_page()` that return the name of actual page.

```
$page = get_actual_page();
switch ($page){
    case 'home':
        $content = 'stuff 1';
        break;
    case 'about':
        $content = 'stuff 2';
        break;
    // other cases...
}

echo '<div class="strapline">'.$content.'</div>';
```

The code would be much cleaner, more readable and more maintainable this way.

Comment: This is working, with no errors but it seems to only pick up the first case and display it for every page.. 

<?php
 $page = is_page();
 witch ($page_id){
 case 'home':
 $content = 'Find out whats happening 1'; etc...

I've probably used the wrong wordpress functions? Would anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know Wordpress, you could check what does `is_page()` return.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your function.php

```
function content($content)
{
    if(is_page('home')){
      return '<div class="home">'.$content.'</div>';
    } else if(is_page('about')){
      return '<div class="about">'.$content.'</div>';
    }
      return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content','content')
```